# Calculating date difference when working with a set of business hours in PHP

Tags: php, time, intervals, difference

I'm working on a help desk app.  Users create tickets, and I'm trying to figure out how to code the Due By time.

Say I have a business hours array that looks like this:

```
$bh['Monday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Monday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Tuesday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Tuesday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Wednesday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Wednesday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Thursday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Thursday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Friday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Friday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
```

And an array with holidays:

```
$holidays = array("Dec 25th","Nov 24th")
```

I also have two other variables:

```
$resolve_within = "5";
$resolve_within_duration = "days";
```

What I have so far:

```
$resolve_within = "5";
$resolve_within_duration = "days";
$holidays = array("Dec 25th","Nov 24th")

$bh['Monday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Monday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Tuesday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Tuesday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Wednesday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Wednesday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Thursday']['start_time'] = "8:00am"
$bh['Thursday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Friday']['start_time'] = "5:00pm"
$bh['Friday']['end_time'] = "5:00pm"


$start = new DateTime('now'); //when the ticket is created
$end = new DateTime('now');
$end->modify('+'.$resolve_within.' '.$resolve_within_duration); //this is essentially the due by time, adding 5 days to 'now'


$interval = $end->diff($start);

// total days
$days = $interval->days;

// create an iterateable period of date (P1D equates to 1 day)
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($period as $dt) {
    $curr = $dt->format('D');

    //adjust days for holidays
    if (in_array($dt->format('M jS'), $holidays)) {
       $days--;
    }
}

echo "Ticket is due in $days days.";
```

So, given the start date and end date, how can I come up with the due by time, excluding dates in the `$holidays` array, and also taking for account the times and days in the `$bh` (business hours) array?

For example, if someone creats a ticket on Wed 8/23/16 at 3:00pm, and there's a Holiday on Friday.  The due by time should be Thursday 8/11/16 at 3:pm.  Keeping in mind also that the duration can be hours and not days.

For example, some tickets by be tagged as Urgent, therefore the $resolve_within value might be "4" and the $resolve_within_duration will be "hours"

Comment: Can you walk us through more specifically where you are stuck? It seems that your algorithm should be to add 5 days (resolve time) to the create time, then modify this by +1d (repeatedly) if it lands on a holiday, then modify by +1h (repeatedly) if it is not within business hours. It might additionally be a good idea to have a "weekend days" array so you can bump up +1d at a time for weekly non-operational days.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement the business hours array into the foreach loop.

Comment: (Updated my comment above). Broadly, I would say have another loop.

Comment: Style point: the community prefers post titles here not to be tagged i.e. `<problem>, PHP` or `<problem> PHP/Jquery/Mysql` etc - your question history indicates quite a bit of this! Just write titles in ordinary grammatical English if you can - there are several related discussions on _Meta_, if you're interested.

Comment: @halfer, gotcha will do.

Comment: If you change your assignment for `$curr` to `$curr = $dt->format('l');` then you'll have the fulltext of the day of the week. Check `!empty($bh[$curr])` and that should let you know if it's a weekday. Then you can grab the hours and roll forward as needed the way halfer described above

Comment: I'd like to work at this place: `$bh['Friday']['start_time'] = "5:00pm"`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and store times as integers from 0-23, it's much easier to do comparisons than with am/pm strings